# Casperjs exec page javascript

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I try to parse a script tag javascript variable but unfortunately the output is null.
The HTML code is

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var javascriptValues = {"key":"test"};

//-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My casperjs part is:

```
var foo = this.evaluate(function() {
            return document.javascriptValues;
    });
    this.echo(foo.innerHTML);
```

Is there any way to exec and print page variable via casperjs?

Comment: 1. The page script is not valid. Delete the HTML comments. 2. the returned js object has no `innerHTML` property. You probably mean `foo.key`. Also you cannot return DOM elements from the page context.

Comment: To answer your question: `javascriptValues` is a global variable, so you can access it via `window.javascriptValues` inside the `evaluate` function.

Comment: does'n work, by access window.javascriptValues get the message "undefined"

Comment: What casper/phantom version do you have? Are you sure that the variable is actually outside of all functions? Otherwise it can't work.

Comment: casper v=1.1.0-beta3 , phantomjs v=1.9.0 and yes code is outsite of functions .... casper.then(function () {
        this.evaluate(function() {
                this.echo(window.javascriptValues);
        });

}); or console.log(window.javascriptValues); same result = undefined

Comment: Please run [this minimal script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/194ef8f535754b8ad221) to reproduce your problem. If it does not print `[object Object]` then you need to update your phantom and casper probably too. Also `echo` is not defined inside `evaluate`. Please edit your code and make it valid by removing the HTML comments inside the page javascript block.

Comment: it's working, Artjom B. thank you WM !